# Automatically assigning different sound outputs for different external screens

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have two different external screens, television and monitor. My TV has speaker but my monitor doesn't have. Whenever I switch my external screen (Only 1 HDMI input) from TV to monitor or vice versa, I need to change the sound output settings manually.

- using monitor -> sound must play on laptop
- using TV -> sound must play on TV

Is there a way or a terminal command for me to set different settings for my two external screens so that I don't have to change the sound settings every time I switch screens? (22.04.2 LTS)

Comment: You would need to write your own script to do this.